# C++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, makefile, compiler-errors

****NOTE PLEASE**:** I read the question and their answers but still, I haven't found any answer to my problem so I had to ask this question.

I have a macOS and kali Linux laptop and when I compaile this same code in my iMac the code work fine (I have some errors in exeption but I'm trying to fix them).
but when I tried to compaile the same code in my kali linux I got the following error:

```
└─$ make                                                                                                                                                                                         1 ⨯
g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I.  -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I.  -c -o Bureaucrat.o Bureaucrat.cpp
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I. -o Bureaucrat main.o Bureaucrat.o -I Bureaucrat.hpp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Makefile:27: Bureaucrat] Error 1
```

my makefile:

```
SRCS            = main.cpp \
Bureaucrat.cpp \

OBJS            = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

CPP             = clang++
RM              = rm -f
CPPFLAGS        = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -I.

NAME            = Bureaucrat

all:            $(NAME)

$(NAME):        $(OBJS) Bureaucrat.hpp
                $(CPP) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $(OBJS) -I Bureaucrat.hpp

clean:
                $(RM) $(OBJS)

fclean:         clean
                $(RM) $(NAME)

re:             fclean $(NAME)

.PHONY:         all clean fclean re
```

Comment: Clang standard C++ library is libc++. Try to add -stdlib=libc++ to CPPFLAGS.

Comment: -I expects the include directory part y, you pass the file name Bureaucrat.hpp.

Comment: I added it flag you said about and I got this error `g++  -Wall -Wextra -Werror -stdlib=libc++  -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
make: *** [<builtin>: main.o] Error 1`

Comment: CPP sets C preprocessor. OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o) uses g++ instead of clang++. You want to set and use CXX.

Comment: @S.M. I can't use any command other than `clang++`

Comment: If you can't, why are you using g++ to compile object files? You mixed compilers on different build stages. Not a good idea.

Comment: but I didn't use `g++` in the makefile so I don't understand why the compiler use it

Comment: I already explained, because you set the invalid variable CPP, responsible for C preprocessor.

Comment: so how can I set it to use clang++ instead of g++

Comment: You should use `CXX` and `CXXFLAGS` variables names instead of `CPP` and `CPPFLAGS`: these are `make` [expects](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-CC) to be set for c++ compiler.